# What Is The Best Weapon (Base Damage Stat)?

Tags: fallout-4

I Was exploring a factory where there was a lot of death claws so I got ruined. What is the best weapon on the game because I heard there is a nice bit of loot in their.

Comment: Big Boy might be great, but it can be messy and hazardous in close quarters. I suggest finding a Gauss Rifle instead. I've been one-shotting the Deathclaws ever since I got mine.

Comment: You want the best single-shot damage (which is what you have in the answer), or the best damage-per-second?

Comment: If you can find a high ROF wounding weapon it'll top most anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Big Boy is with 468 base damage and 8.1 damage per second

Answer (score 3):

A Neverending Laser Musket can do an arbitrarily large amount of damage if you crank it long enough.

Per [Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects):

> as the musket uses its "clip" to store the crank charge, and this mod sets the clip size to the amount of ammo in your inventory, the mod effectively removes the crank limit. Since the damage of the weapon is based on how many cranks you can give it, this gives that single shot a devastating amount of damage. For example, at 200 cranks, a single shot can do about 30,000 damage.

Answer (score 0):

The *Spray n' Pray*. It costs around 2.7 thousand caps. It shoots explosive bullets and takes .45 caliber rounds. You can buy it from either [Cricket](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cricket), at Diamond City or at Vault 81.

Comment: This *is* an answer to the question, but I think it needs the damage and rate of fire numbers. I also think you're saying this does the most because of the explosive damage, so there should probably be some kind of explanation of that as well.

Comment: I can confirm that this weapon is insane in the hands of a companion, especially if you can get it before level 30 or so. The splash damage from the explosive shots means that it's okay when Piper misses 70% of her shots. I saw Valentine take out a Deathclaw in the 20's with this thing, with no help from me at all.